# Need help improving SQL DELETE performance

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, sql-delete

I have two relations, Customer and Adress. First of all, I don't have permission to modify the DB (like making a new raltion for customers and adresses).
What I need is, given a list of States, delete customers who either have Adress1 or Adress2 related to that state.
What I'm doing below is very slow, so any help would be appreciated.

```
foreach (State state in listOfStates)
{
  query = 
   "DELETE FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM ADRESS
     WHERE CUSTOMER.ADRESS1 = ADRESS.ID
     AND STATE = " + state + ")";
  cmd.CommandText = query;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  query = 
   "DELETE FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM ADRESS
     WHERE CUSTOMER.ADRESS2 = ADRESS.ID
     AND STATE = " + state + ")";
  cmd.CommandText = query;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

Customer
+----------+---------+---------+--+
|   Name   | Adress1 | Adress2 |  |
+----------+---------+---------+--+
| John Doe |       1 |       2 |  |
| Victor   |       3 |       4 |  |
| Renat    |       5 |       6 |  |
+----------+---------+---------+--+

Adress

+----+--------+------+------------+
| ID | Street | City |   State    |
+----+--------+------+------------+
|  1 | xxx    | xxx  | California |
|  2 | xxx    | xxx  | Florida    |
|  3 | xxx    | xxx  | California |
|  4 | xxx    | xxx  | Ohio       |
|  5 | xxx    | xxx  | Virginia   |
|  6 | xxx    | xxx  | Colorado   |
+----+--------+------+------------+
```

Comment: I'm working with c# and Access

Comment: Are there SQL commands really correct ? Actually they perform a operation like: "if  exists some record, then **delete ALL records** from the table `customer`". That is, these queries always delete all customers. If this is really what you want to do, then the fastest method will be delete and recreate the table.

Comment: The first query deletes customers with Adress1 related to the current state. The second one does the same but with Adress2 .

Comment: `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE EXISTS (some condition)` will always delete ALL records if the condition is true, I think you need to do more tests

Comment: @krokodilko: You are mistaken. The subquery is correlated to the delete statement. It checks the customer's address only. Hence only customers whose address is in the looked up state gets deleted.

Comment: @krokodilko Not really, `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE (some condition involving table1)` will only delete the relevant rows. In this case, the filter does involve the `customer` table and as such, only relevant rows will be deleted.

Comment: Yes, you are right, temporary amnesia, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you build an IN clause for the states. If your listOfStates is `List<string>`, this will be:

```
string states = "'" + string.Join("','", listOfStates) + "'";
```

(This would result in something like `'Arizona','Kentucky','Tennessee'`, i.e. a comma-separated string with all states enclosed in single quotes.)

If listOfStates is not `List<string>`, then adjust the above to meet your collection type, e.g.

```
string states = "'" + string.Join("','", listOfStates.Select(state => state.Name)) + "'";
```

Then run a single delete statement for all states:

```
query = 
 "DELETE FROM customer
  WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM adress
   WHERE adress.id IN (customer.adress1, customer.adress2)
   AND adress.state IN (" + states + "))";

cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I like this approach. Although the DELETE query is still slow, the average time improved exponentially, since it's evaluated only once.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with Access, Joins are usually much faster than WHERE EXISTS clauses.

This should be doable with a composite JOIN. The following is air code but should work.

Access likes lots of parentheses in non-trivial JOIN clauses.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CUSTOMER c
  INNER JOIN ADRESS a
    ON ((c.ADRESS1 = a.ID OR c.ADRESS2 = a.ID)
        AND (a.STATE = <state>)
       )
```

If the above works, simply replace SELECT by DELETE.

You can also combine this with Thorsten's suggestion:

```
AND (a.STATE IN ('state1', 'state2'))
```

Comment: . . In my experience (which is mostly on other databases), `join`s are not "usually much faster" than `exists`.  Do you have a reference for this on MS Access?

Comment: No, only personal experience with the Access database engine. I should have been more specific, I guess.

Comment: . . Have you run a specific timing on this, particularly with the appropriate indexes?